# Sandwich icon position in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I would like to know if there's a way to put the the sandwich icon on the left side of the title name.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  
  dashboardBody()
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just use an image in your `www` folder.  Try this

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = div(img(src = 'hotdog.png', title = "A Test Application", height = "30px"),
                "My Title", style = "position: relative; margin:-3px 0px 0px 5px; display:right-align;"
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardSidebar(),
  
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Actually is the .sidebar-toggle element.